# Не работает message.delete()

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord

def check(text ,list):
    for i in list:
        print(text.find(i))
        if text.find(i) > -1:
            print(True)
            return True
    return False
            

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author == client.user:
        if check(message.content, ["A", "B"]):
            await message.delete()
client.run('ТОКЕН')
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\python\discord\alex.py", line 25, in on_message
    await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 521, in purge
    return await discord.abc._purge_helper(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 181, in _purge_helper
    await ret[-1].delete()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 841, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_message(self.channel.id, self.id)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 738, in request
    raise Forbidden(response, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: откуда взялось "message.delete()"? В приведенном коде такого нет. В ошибке тоже речь не об этом

Comment: У бота мало прав. Поставьте его роль на самый верх

Comment: Всё равно не работает :(

Answer (score 0):

Боту не хватает прав, возможно, на сайте дискорд девелопер вы не дали бота разрешение на работу с сообщениями или же у него нет прав для управлением сообщениями на самом сервере